# PHP MySQL Push and Pull from Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, push, pull

I am having a problem with my PHP code. I have a series of columns in MySQL database, PotVal, Current, ID, kWh and costKwh. Where ID is AUTO_INCREMENT, PotVal and Current are from a Text file - these are working correctly and storing the data fine. However i would like to take PotVal which is actually sensed power and convert this to KiloWatt hours using (PotVal*1)/(900) (don't worry I know its 1000 normally not 900) - this is also working fine and outputting the data in realtime, however I am trying to store this value in my kWh colum. Next I use this kWh column to carry out another calculation for cost per kWh using (kWh*18.56). However due to not storing data in kWh column I am getting 0.00 output and I can't rectify it!

So in summary why am I not able to store in kWh? And also I want to display the value to two decimal places but its actually displaying to six decimal places!

```
<?php 

header('Refresh: 1.5');

// Set relevent pseudo-variables
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $table = 'received_data';
    $drop = 'DROP TABLE received_data';
    $iwemsdatafile = 'IWEMSData.txt';

// Connect to MySQL

    $dbconnect = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
        or die('Unable to connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
    //  echo 'Connected to MySQL<br>';

    mysql_query($drop);

// Create database, table and columns

    $cdb = 'CREATE DATABASE IWEMS_Data';
    //  echo 'IWEMS_Data has been created<br /><hr />';

    $selectdb = mysql_select_db('IWEMSData',$dbconnect)
        or die('Could not select IWEMSData');
    //  echo 'Connected to IWEMSData database<br />';

    mysql_query($drop);

    $ctb = 'CREATE TABLE received_data
    (
    Current DECIMAL(30,2) NOT NULL,
    PotVal DECIMAL(30,2) NOT NULL,
    kWh DECIMAL(30,2) NOT NULL,
    costkWh DECIMAL(30,2) NOT NULL,
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID,PotVal,Current)
    )';

    mysql_query($ctb, $dbconnect);
    //  echo 'Received_Data Table has been created<br />';
    //  echo 'Current, PotVal and ID columns have been created<br /><hr />';

// Push IWEMSData.txt data into MySQL database

    mysql_query
    ('
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "IWEMSData.txt" 
    REPLACE INTO TABLE received_data 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY " " 
    LINES TERMINATED BY "\\r\\n"
    (PotVal, Current)
    ;')
    or die('Error Loading Data File.<br>' . mysql_error());

// Pull IWEMSData from MySQL database

    $seldat = 'SELECT * FROM received_data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1';


    $data = mysql_query($seldat) 
        or die('Error retrieving data: ' . mysql_error());

// Display data on web browser

    while ($finalrow = mysql_fetch_array($data))
    {
        echo '<hr /> Apparent Power<br />';
        echo $finalrow['PotVal'];
        echo ' Watts';
        echo '<br /><hr />';
        echo 'Detected Current<br />';
        echo $finalrow['Current'];
        echo ' Amps';
        echo '<br /><hr />';
    }

// Display per kWh data on web browser

    $perkWh = 'SELECT *, (PotVal/900) AS kWh
    FROM received_data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1';

    $qperkWh =mysql_query($perkWh) or die('Error');

    while ($finalkWh = mysql_fetch_array($qperkWh))
    {
    echo 'kWh<br />';
    echo $finalkWh['kWh'];
    echo '<br /><hr />';
    }


// Display cost per kWh data on web browser

    $cperkWh = 'SELECT *, (kWh*18.67) AS costkWh
    FROM received_data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1';

    $cqperkWh =mysql_query($cperkWh) or die('Error');

    while ($cfinalkWh = mysql_fetch_array($cqperkWh))
    {
    echo 'Cost kWh<br />';
    echo $cfinalkWh['costkWh'];
    echo '<br /><hr />';
    }

// Close Database connection when complete

    mysql_close($dbconnect);
?>
```

(I bet it's something simple... again!)

Comment: where is your insert statement?

Comment: From how you have it set up, why do you need the second select?  Just do the calculation in PHP: `$finalkWh['kWh']*18.67`?  You limit the query to 1 anyways, so you don't need the while loops, and you don't need the second query since you have all the information from the first anyways. ^^

Comment: Yogesh thanks ill look into that different approach and let you know how i get on! Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$perkWh = 'SELECT *, (PotVal/900) AS kWh
FROM received_data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1';
```

I think you already have a `kWh` column in `received_data` table, so you can not naming `(PotVal/900)` as `kWh`

same problem in `$cperkWh = 'SELECT *, (kWh*18.67) AS costkWh
    FROM received_data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1';`
 with `costkWh`

Comment: So if i remove the kWh column it will create it for me?

Comment: Yes...and if you need it, you can use `SELECT *, (PotVal/900) AS kWh1...` for example

Comment: @user2300686 what do you want to do really? do you like to update `kWh` column to `(PotVal/900)`?..if yes , you should use `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statement, not `SELECT`

Comment: Done that worked! Thank you very much. E-Beer for you. However... its displaying too many decimal numbers (6) when i only want (2). This is the line im using where i want both echo to have 0.00 format.

Comment: $perkWh = 'SELECT *, (PotVal/900) as kWh
 FROM received_data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1';
 
 $qperkWh =mysql_query($perkWh) or die('Error');
 
 while ($costperkWh = mysql_fetch_array($qperkWh))
 {
 echo 'Your kWh usage is <br />';
 echo $costperkWh['kWh'];
 echo ' KiloWatt hour<hr />';
 echo 'Your kWh cost is <br />';
 echo $costperkWh['kWh']*18.67;
 echo ' Pence per hour<hr />';
 }

Comment: That didn't work mate, im probably putting it in wrong.             echo DECIMAL($costperkWh['kWh'], 2, '.', '');

Answer (score 1):

I see you have uppercase letters in your queries. When I was working with this type of queries I have memories that it had some weird problems with using uppercase ones. So I really recommend you not to use uppercase letters and use ONLY lowercase ones.

And if you want to use uppercase letters be sure to enclose all your database, column, table names in quote marks I mean use like

```
`kWh`
```

And check if the problem persists. This COULD not be the issue but it may be it. :)

and A suggestion is that don't use `mysql*` functions they are likely to be deprecated and they are open to a lot of security problems like Injections. Use `PDO` instead. you can see the doc on the PHP documentation.